# Notifying parent process to resume working

Tags: c++, parent-child, ipc

I'm creating a child process and loading a 3rd-party program.
After loading, the child process is doing some IO operations that I have no control on.

In a perfect world, the child process would finish his magic-IO-mambo-jumbo and the parent process will initialize a unit that depends on a successful magic.

How can I make sure that the magic has finished happening and I can load up that unit?

By the way, I'm using C/C++.

Comment: Does this need to work on a specific operating system, or does it need to be portable?

Comment: Linux. Currently I'm  putting the parent to sleep for 10 seconds, but that's a lousy coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for some kind of interprocess communication.  This is going to be os-specific, although there are more compatible wrappers like boost.interprocess.  In particular, you're going to want some sort of synchronization mechanism: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html

Comment: I can't change the child process. It's a 3rd party, and once I use `execvp` to change the entire memory of the process I'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: Does the child process exit once the IO operations are done? Because if so you can just wait on it to exit... Otherwise it's going to be tough if the child process doesn't give you any kind of signal that it's done. You might be stuck just doing a sleep in that case, unless you can do something really dirty like monitor a file to see if it's in use.

Comment: The child process is like a service to my system. Thus, both parent and child need to keep running. The child has no file I can monitor (or at least one that I know of), and no signal/function I can use to check that it has finished loading up and can now be used.
I think I might just leave the `sleep(10)` although might be too long, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yeah, to put it bluntly, you're screwed.  The only way you can write a robust application is if you can reliably detect if your unit (the one that depends on the child process) doesn't initialize correctly.  In that case you could wait a little longer then try again.

Comment: You made me laugh =). Thnx @Nathan